# Any way to make sysfs file immutable?

Tags: selinux, sysfs

I'm trying to make `/sys/fs/selinux/enforce` always contain "1", and prevent it from being changed.

I've been able to do this on `/etc/selinux/config` by running `chattr +i /etc/selinux/config`

However, when i try this on a file in the selinux sysfs I get the following error:

```
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on /sys/fs/selinux/enforce
```

I'm assuming this is due to the sysfs files being different from actual files.

Any known way to accomplish the same outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to patch the kernel.

Files in `/sys` and `/proc` are purely virtual, you cannot change their permissions using normal Linux utilities.